# VS Code, No code completion for c# code inside cshtml razor

Tags: visual-studio-code

Im having a problem with using Visual Studio Code for editing CSHTML files. im using windows. This is ordinary web matrix page not MVC..

```
@{

MyClass my = new MyClass();

MyClass.

}
```

No intellisense at all... Am I missing an extension or something..

Comment: Check https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/153

Answer (score 4):

It's something others have noticed as well. Apparently it's an upcoming feature with no ETA.

david-driscoll:

> We'll be adding support to OmniSharp eventually to support Razor, sadly I don't have a specific timeline. This is mainly because it's not a very easy problem to solve, but it is something we want to get working.

https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/168

Update: This has been released, and is under active development see: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.